# Why is UI not updating when OnPropertyChange is called?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm relatively new to MVVM and I am trying to follow the principles. I have an issue where the Model is updated externally. The model then raises an event and the ViewModel handles it, updates the relevant fields. The appropriate fields then raise the onPropertyChange event. However the UI is not updating. If I reload the page the view is updated. My Xaml:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding EBBusBreakers}" >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="BlanchedAlmond" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0.5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Padding="1">
                        <Border.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                            <Style TargetType="Button">
                                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="1" />
                                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
                                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Resources>
                        <Grid Margin="0">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0"/>
                            <TextBlock FontSize="12" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" >
                                <TextBlock.Text>
                                    <Binding Path="Status" PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel="High" />
                                </TextBlock.Text>
                            </TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ApplicationName}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                            <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="On" Command="{Binding TurnOnCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Off" Command="{Binding TurnOffCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Reset" Command="{Binding ResetCommand}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class BreakerCollectionViewModel {
 private ObservableCollection<IBreakerNodeControl> _ebBusBreakers;
        public ObservableCollection<IBreakerNodeControl> EBBusBreakers
    {
        get => _ebBusBreakers;
        set => SetProperty(ref _ebBusBreakers, value);
    }
}

   public class BreakerViewModel : BaseViewModel, IBreakerNodeControl
{
    private readonly S201Breaker _breaker;

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetProperty(ref _name, value);
    }

    private string _status;

    public string Status
    {
        get => _status;
        set => SetProperty(ref _status, value);
    }

    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand TurnOnCommand => new RelayCommand(param => TurnOn());
    public RelayCommand TurnOffCommand => new RelayCommand(param => TurnOff());
    public RelayCommand ResetCommand => new RelayCommand(param => Reset());

    public BreakerViewModel(S201Breaker breaker)
    {
        Name = breaker.Name;
        _breaker = breaker;
        //Bind to property changed event to update status
        _breaker.PropertyChanged += UpdateState;
    }

    private void UpdateState(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (sender is S201Breaker breaker)
        {
            Status = breaker.State.ToString();
        }
    }
    
    public void TurnOn()
    {
        _breaker.DesiredState = BreakerTargetStateEnum.On;
    }

    public void TurnOff()
    {
        _breaker.DesiredState = BreakerTargetStateEnum.Off;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _breaker.DesiredState = BreakerTargetStateEnum.Reset;
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
public class S201Breaker : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyThatChanged = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyThatChanged));
    }

    private BreakerStateEnum _state;
    public BreakerStateEnum State
    {
        get => _state;
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    protected S201Breaker(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        State = BreakerStateEnum.Unknown;
    }
}
```

EDIT: My BaseViewModel (SetProperty):

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    public bool SetProperty<T>(ref T property, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = "")
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(property, value))
        {
            return false;
        }

        property = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(name);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> _errorsByPropertyName = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        if (propertyName == null)
        {
            var allPropertyErrors = new List<string>();
            foreach (var keyValuePair in _errorsByPropertyName)
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.ForEach(error => allPropertyErrors.Add(error));
            }

            return allPropertyErrors;
        }
        else
        {
            return _errorsByPropertyName.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? _errorsByPropertyName[propertyName] : null;
        }
    }

    public bool HasErrors => _errorsByPropertyName.Any();

    protected void AddError(string error, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!_errorsByPropertyName.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            _errorsByPropertyName[propertyName] = new List<string>();
        }

        if (_errorsByPropertyName[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            return;
        }
        _errorsByPropertyName[propertyName].Add(error);
        OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    protected void ClearErrors([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!_errorsByPropertyName.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            return;
        }
        _errorsByPropertyName.Remove(propertyName);
        OnErrorsChanged(propertyName);
    }

    private void OnErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        ErrorsChanged?.Invoke(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #region Events
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;
    #endregion

}
```

EDIT: Adding interface code

```
    public interface IBreakerNodeControl
{
    string Name { get; }
    string Status { get; }
    string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    RelayCommand TurnOnCommand { get; }
    RelayCommand TurnOffCommand { get; }
    RelayCommand ResetCommand { get; }
}
```

I have simplified the xaml and class though it should show what I am trying (rightly or wrongly) to achieve.

I have tried the following:

- Removing the collection and updating just the one instance
- Following the events (looks like it should be updating as normal)
- Setting the tracelevel to high (this shows that the event is on triggered. Actual message: Got PropertyChanged event from BreakerViewModel)
- Changing the updateSourceTrigger to onPropertyChange
- Setting binding mode to oneWay
- Implementing INorifyPropertyChanged in IBreakerNodeControl

I am aware that these are "simple" fixes. I am unsure though what the problem is as I can step from the model change through to the viewmodel and the viewmodel raises the event (as shown by the trace).

If there are any issues please let me know and I will amend my question to help. Any improvements are welcomed as it will help me improve!

TL;DR: Implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, change the property and the ui doesnt update until the page is refreshed even though trace says event is received.

Comment: Is the S201Breaker State updated from a thread other than the UI thread?

Comment: Maybe the property changed event is being ignored. I've seen code where we (mysteriously) had to explicitly say a leaf viewmodel implements inotifypropertychanged. And your observablecollection is of an interface. You could stick , INotifyPropertyChanged on the inheritance list or maybe change to the actual class type.

Comment: Property change notification should automatically be marshalled to the ui thread. @Clemens

Comment: @Andy I know, but perhaps there is ("mysteriously") still an issue with it. It would be easy to find out. And the fact that binding trace apparently says "Got PropertyChanged event from BreakerViewModel" rules out *your* argumentation.

Comment: I assume your SetProperty method doesn't raise the OnPropertyChanged event. Can you post the code for it?

Comment: @Cosmin That assumption is wrong. Also just because there is "Got PropertyChanged event from BreakerViewModel" in the Text Binding trace output.

Comment: The OP's post says the trace indicates "Got PropertyChanged event from BreakerViewModel".  Which does seem to rather imply setproperty must be raising property changed.

Comment: @Andy And it also proves that "Maybe the property changed event is being ignored" is not true.

Comment: @Clemens I thought trace used a separate mechanism. If it's actually the same as the binding itself, then the binding got the change notification and should hit the getter. Is the new value definitely different? SetProperty is changing the backer before raising change notification?

Comment: A broken SetProperty implementation would certainly explain the observed behaviour.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the base class for completion (includes the setproperty() for inspection). I didnt originally as the base class is used elsewhere and works there.

Comment: I see the BreakerCollectionViewModel doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. I'd put that too.

Comment: @Cosmin It does, otherwise there would be no SetProperty method. OP just forgot to post the full declaration. For the scope of the question it isn't relevant anyway.

Comment: If you add , INotifyPropertyChanged to the implementation list of the IBreakerNodeControl interface does that make any difference?

Comment: @Clemens You can have the SetProperty (OnPropertyChanged) without the INotifyPropertyChanged, but it won't have the expected behavior though.

Comment: @Cosmin Sure, but that is unlikely (and still totally irrelevant here). Don't you think OP would very likely use the same BaseViewModel class for all their view models?

Comment: @Clemens I couldn't answer that, I'm just commenting on what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Cosmin And in the flood of irrelevant comments, things that matter get lost. Sorry to say that.

Comment: @NinjaArekku You need to provide more details about your code. What you are showing here should just work.

Comment: The missing thing is what the interface IBreakerNodeControl implements. I guess that doesn't include inpc and I guess this is the only place he uses it. 10 seconds to try that theory out.

Comment: @clemens what would you like to know? If it’s within my ability I’ll give you the earth to solve this! The reason I raised this question is because I think it should work. I can step through and show all the events are triggered correctly and in order but nothing changes until the page is refreshed.

Comment: @Andy I added the INPC to the IBreakerNodeControl interface and nothing changed. The INPC is implented in the BaseViewModel and is inherited by my breakerViewModel. I have also updated the question to include my interface.

Comment: @Clemens Thankyou for the gentle prodding! I hadnt taken into account that the updates are firing within a task. I'll add what I was doing and how I fixed it below for posterirty and furhter discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicussion and prodding from Clemens in the comments made me realise that I am updating the models and subsequently the viewmodels within a task. After a bit of research I came up with the following solution by syncing UI contexts.

```
    private void ProcessMessageQueue(TaskScheduler uiContext)
    {
        while (!CancelToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            ResponseResetSignal.WaitOne();
            while (CommsToLogicQueue.TryDequeue(out var incomingMessage))
            {
                var result = incomingMessage;
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessMessage(result), CancelToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, uiContext);
            }
        }
    }
```